# Generate 2 normal vectors with specific correlation values across all levels

Tags: r, correlation, normal-distribution

Using `rmvnorm`, I can generate 2 standard normal vectors **x** and **y** with the property that they have certain correlations across different levels of some categorical variable. For instance, if I want **x** and **y** to be 25%, 50% and 75% correlated in 3 levels, I can do:

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(tidyverse)

n_obs <- 15000
set.seed(42)

z.1 <- rmvnorm(n_obs/3, sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.25, 0.25, 1), ncol = 2))
z.2 <- rmvnorm(n_obs/3, sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), ncol = 2))
z.3 <- rmvnorm(n_obs/3, sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.75, 0.75, 1), ncol = 2))
z <- rbind(z.1, z.2, z.3)

df <- tibble(x = z[,1],
             y = z[,2],
             cat.a = c(rep("A1", n_obs/3), rep("A2", n_obs/3), rep("A3", n_obs/3)),
             cat.b = rep(c("B1", "B2"), n_obs/2))

df %>%
  group_by(cat.a) %>%
  summarize(cor = cor(x, y))
```

which returns

```
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   cat.a       cor
##   <chr>     <dbl>
## 1    A1 0.2381375
## 2    A2 0.4880839
## 3    A3 0.7508989
```

Is there a way to have more than 1 categorical variable such that I can generate 2 vectors that have desired correlations across all levels in each category? For instance, I can manipulate **x** as follows

```
df %>%
  group_by(cat.b) %>%
  summarize(cor = cor(x, y))

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   cat.b       cor
##   <chr>     <dbl>
## 1    B1 0.4941775
## 2    B2 0.4940611

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(cat.b == "B1", x + 0.2*y,
                    ifelse(cat.b == "B2", x - 0.2*y,
                           x))) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(scale(x)))

df2 %>%
  group_by(cat.b) %>%
  summarize(cor = cor(x, y))

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   cat.b       cor
##   <chr>     <dbl>
## 1    B1 0.6239066
## 2    B2 0.3207415
```

which changes the correlations across the second category without drastically affecting those in the first one.

```
df2 %>%
  group_by(cat.a) %>%
  summarize(cor = cor(x, y))

## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   cat.a       cor
##   <chr>     <dbl>
## 1    A1 0.2330728
## 2    A2 0.4818041
## 3    A3 0.7359741
```

Is there, however, a way to do this systematically? In particular, I want to be able to pre-set specific correlation values for the second category as well.